# Macro Not Executing

Tags: vba, excel, macros, copy-paste

I have the below code. What I am trying to achieve is the Macro should look down the country column. Column F. Find a country then copy and paste all data for that country to a new sheet. name the tab with that country and do this again for the next country in column F

The Marco compiles just fine but nothing happens any help would be greatly appreciated.

The code is below and I have also attached a pic [image]

```
Option Explicit

Sub Filter()

Dim wsCL As Worksheet
Set wsCL = Worksheets("CountryList")

Dim rCL As Range, rCountry As Range
Set rCL = wsCL.Range("A1:A201")

Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Set ws1 = Worksheets("Sheet1")

Dim lRow As Long
lRow = ws1.Range("A" & ws1.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For Each rCountry In rCL

    'check if country exists
    Dim rTest As Range
    Set rTest = ws1.Range("F1:F" & lRow).Find(rCountry.Value2, lookat:=xlWhole)

    If Not rTest Is Nothing Then 'if country is found create sheet and copy data

        Dim wsNew As Worksheet
        Worksheets.Add (ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count)
        Set wsNew = ActiveSheet
        wsNew.Name = rCountry.Value2
        ws1.Range("A1:Q1").Copy wsNew.Range("A1") 'place header row

        With ws1.Range("A1:Q" & lRow)
            .AutoFilter 10, rCountry.Value2
            .Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy wsNew.Range("B1") 'copy data for country under header
            .AutoFilter
        End With

    End If

Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**edited**, amending line:

```
With .Range("A1:Q" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1))
```

with

```
With .Range("A1:Q" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row)
```

the typo (I must have written it thousands of times in the correct form) didn't break the code but it was (unintentionally) referring to a range in columns "A:Q" from row 1 to the last sheet one, instead of the last non empty one in column "A". Quite a big range...and potentially breaking code if shared among differently "aged" excel files, standing the sheet maximum rows jump form nearly 65 thousands prior to excel 2007 to the actual more than 1 million

---

there are two errors

- `Worksheets.Add (ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count)`

  must be:

  `Worksheets.Add Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)`
- `.AutoFilter 10, rCountry.Value2`

  must be:

  `.AutoFilter 6, rCountry.Value2`

since Country is the 6th column of your database

furthermore I'd suggest you to use:

```
Set rCL = wsCL.Range("A1:A201").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlTextValues)
```

to have subsequent `For Each rCountry In rCL` loop operate only on relevant (filled with a text value) cells

Finally, you may want to try this refactored code:

**edited** after realizing that CountryList is the sheet with all data and Sheet1 is the sheet with "Country" list...

**edited 2** after today OP's clarifications

```
Option Explicit

Sub Filter()
    Dim rCountry As Range, helpCol As Range

    With Worksheets("CountryList") '<--| refer to data worksheet
        With .UsedRange
            Set helpCol = .Resize(1, 1).Offset(, .Columns.Count) '<--| get a "helper" column just at the right of used range, it'll be used to store unique country names in
        End With

        With .Range("A1:Q" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row) '<--| refer to its columns "A:Q" from row 1 to last non empty row of column "A"
            .Columns(6).AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CopyToRange:=helpCol, Unique:=True '<-- call AdvancedFilter on 6th column of the referenced range and store its unique values in "helper" column
            Set helpCol = Range(helpCol.Offset(1), helpCol.End(xlDown)) '<--| set range with unique names in (skip header row)
            For Each rCountry In helpCol '<--| iterate over unique country names range (skip header row)
                .AutoFilter 6, rCountry.Value2 '<--| filter data on country field (6th column) with current unique country name
                If Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(103, .Cells.Resize(, 1)) > 1 Then '<--| if any cell other than header ones has been filtered...
                    Worksheets.Add Worksheets(Worksheets.Count) '<--... add new sheet
                    ActiveSheet.name = rCountry.Value2  '<--... rename it
                    .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy ActiveSheet.Range("A1") 'copy data for country under header
                End If
            Next
        End With
        .AutoFilterMode = False '<--| remove autofilter and show all rows back
    End With
    helpCol.Offset(-1).End(xlDown).Clear '<--| clear helper column (header included)        
End Sub
```

Comment: i like the refactored code but I am getting error 1004 when i compile. Is something wrong?The line a fault is **".AutoFilter 6, rCountry.Value2"** '<--| filter data on country field (6th column) with current country name

Comment: didn't realize that _CountryList_ is the sheet with all data and _Sheet1_ is the sheet with "Country" list...see edited code

Comment: thank you for the help. I have tried the edited code but i am now getting run time error 1004 no cells were found on line `Set rCL = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A201").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlTextValues) '<--| set country names range`

Comment: The code was tested. check if range from "A1" to "A201" in "Sheet1" worksheet of the currently active workbook there are actually _text_ values.

Comment: @PhilipConnell: did you get through it?

Comment: no unfortunately. I cant have all the information as txt. i need date format and number in there also. Thank you for your continued support. is there another way?

Comment: "Country" names can be _numbers_ or _dates_?

Comment: Im sorry im a bit lost Country names is just text. like "Austria" or "Germany" there are no numbers involved in the country column. Is there anyway i can be of more help?

Comment: run the code I provided you once you have checked that: 1) both "CountryList" and "Sheet1" worksheets are in the workbook where the macro resides in 2) range "A1:A201" of worksheet "Sheet1" has actually country names, so that `Set rCL = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A201").SpecialCells(xlCellTyp‌​eConstants, xlTextValues)` returns a valid range 3) columns "A:Q" of worksheet "CountryList" contains data and specifically "country" names in column "F"

Comment: @PhilipConnell: how are you getting on?

Comment: Good Morning. Its still not working. Sheet1 is completely blank with this workbook what i need to happen is for the first country on "CountryList" sheet to be populated to sheet1 and then name it after that country then the macro goes back to "countrylist" finds the next country opens up sheet2 names it and brings in the information for that country. every sheet will be blank except for "CountryList" until the macro fires

Comment: BOO YAAH!! that worked perfectly thank you so much for all the Help much respect from Dublin :-) Have a great day :-)

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to match Customer with Country. `rCl` is column A, which is the customer Column.  So for example you are searching 27351637 in Column F, which will never match, so the `rTest` is always nothing and that's why you dont see new worksheets getting created.

If your list of countries is on a different sheet, use the full name, e.g.

`Set rCL = worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A201")`

Comment: `Worksheets.Add (ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count)` needs to be changed to `Worksheets.Add After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)`, too.

Comment: @cyboashu: 1) actually `rCL` is already set with full worksheet reference being `Set rCL = wsCL.Range("A1:A201")` after `Set wsCL = Worksheets("CountryList")` 2) he's not _"trying to match Customer with Country"_ since `rCountry ` is a "country" and `rTest` is matched against `ws1.Range("F1:F" & lRow)` (i.e. with a _country_ field).  The real error is in Autofilter where he's filtering over column 10 of range `ws1.Range("A1:Q" & lRow)`, i.e. "Purpose", instead of column 6 (i.e. "Country").

Comment: `rCountry` is a cell in Column A which is Customer not country. Trying to find 27351637 in a list which contains country names will never return anything. With Full reference I mean to location where he has actual list of Country against which this data set will be compared. This code needs to fix `rTest` first and then rest of the gobly gook. If rTest is always nothing, no matter how effecient the enclosed code is , it will never be reached/ executed.

Comment: @cyboashu:  Without looking at the pic I assumed _CountryList_ would be the "Country" list worksheet and _Sheet1_ the data one, while (oddly, for me at least) it was the opposite!. The code needs only to 1) invert the sheet references (`Set wsCL = Worksheets("Sheet1")` and `Set ws1 = Worksheets("CountryList")` ) or, better, rename sheets properly 2) correct the `Autofilter()` column reference (from 10 to 6)